# XSLT Error : sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml

```
<EVT EvtLevel="1">
    <EVT_EX>
        <FIELD1></FIELD1>
    </EVT_EX>
    <SESNUM>10</SESNUM>
    <WORK_ID>WO-001</WORK_ID>
</EVT>
```

I want to check if any node is present under EVT parent node other than EVT_EX
and SESNUM and assign true/false to a variable. Say the variable is filterFlag

If I perform the check by iterating on each node under EVT using for-each then I get the following error

*A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $filterFlag (false, false, ...)*

As per the above xml filterFlag should have a true value.

For the xml given below the value should be false.

```
<EVT EvtLevel="1">
    <EVT_EX>
        <FIELD1></FIELD1>
    </EVT_EX>
    <SESNUM>10</SESNUM>
</EVT>
```

Please help

Comment: A more general, pure XPath 1.0 expression exists, whose evaluation produces the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't show your code at all we can't tell where the error is but if you want a single boolean value then you need to write an expression that evaluates to a single boolean value and not one that returns a sequence of several boolean values so use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="others" as="xs:boolean" select="exists(* except (EVT_EX, SESNUM))"/>`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Worked as expected
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**In XPath 1.0**:

```
*[not(self::EVT_EX or self::SESNUM)] and 1
```

**XSLT 1.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="EVT">
    <xsl:value-of select="*[not(self::EVT_EX or self::SESNUM)] and 1"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (listed below):

```
<EVT EvtLevel="1">
    <EVT_EX>
        <FIELD1></FIELD1>
    </EVT_EX>
    <SESNUM>10</SESNUM>
</EVT>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the (correct/wanted) result of this evaluation is output:**

```
false
```

**When applied on the other provided XML document**:

```
<EVT EvtLevel="1">
    <EVT_EX>
        <FIELD1></FIELD1>
    </EVT_EX>
    <SESNUM>10</SESNUM>
    <WORK_ID>WO-001</WORK_ID>
</EVT>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
true
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. 
As working with XSLT 2.0 followed the above answer

Comment: @LearnToCode, By design the XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 subsume correspondingly XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0, thus one can use an existing XSLT 1.0 solution with XSLT 2.0. Just change the the value of the `version` attribute of the `xsl:stylesheet` instruction to `2.0`.